# Do accessability standards require that every html page a main tag?

Tags: html, accessibility, semantic-markup

To meet accessability standards, should every page have a `<main>` tag?  I've noticed that major websites sometimes use the `<main>` tag in their pages, and sometimes they do not. Do any of the major accessability standards dictate or suggest that every page should have a `<main>` tag? It seems to make sense, but I'm also not sure what the accessability consequences of *not* having one are.

Comment: what is a main tag? Never seen one xD

Comment: Nah man you don't need a main tag

Comment: The <main> tag specifies the main content of a document.

The content inside the <main> element should be unique to the document. It should not contain any content that is repeated across documents such as sidebars, navigation links, copyright information, site logos, and search forms. And no you do not need one.

Comment: Is it really that unheard of? The first comment has no less than three upvotes at the time I'm posting this, and I'm not sure if the comment, or any of the upvotes, is ironic.

Comment: I think it may have been invented by someone who thought, hey, if we divide the document into three parts, and the top and bottom part are called <header> and <footer>, we should give a tag name to the middle part too!

Comment: You don't *have to* use the `main` tag, but it's very helpful in some situations, one of them being accessibility, the other SEO.

Comment: @BoltClock I honestly didn't know `<main>` existed. Heh. BRB, adding it to everything.

Comment: @ceejayoz: That bad? It was standardized, like, four years ago.

Comment: @BoltClock I too honestly didn't know the tag existed or have seen a site that uses `<main>` - is that for a reason? maybe..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, every html page should/could have the main tag. You must think this tag, as a container to show the main information. It´s not a mandatory tag, but IMO it´s a good practice.

Citing from Mozilla Developers Network:

> The HTML `<main>` element represents the main content of the  of a
>   document or application. The main content area consists of content
>   that is directly related to, or expands upon the central topic of a
>   document or the central functionality of an application.

More information can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main).

I hope it helps you

Comment: Should link to the MDN page too.  I assume it was [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main)

Comment: I´ve inserted the link @Josef Marikle

Comment: Thank you @Josef Marikle :)